# How to seperate data in one variable php

Tags: php

I have data that store in one varible, How to separate this:

```
$data="John Doe 25YR London"
```

Become this:

```
$name="John Doe"; $age="25"; $city="London";
```

Comment: you can split the string how you want and then store it inside vars

Comment: i want to take the name first, then the age, then city. store it to diferrent varible

Comment: you need to split before the first number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all respond, I don't know why I got Downvoted, but I solved my problem :

```
<?php 

// 1. Input data
$input=$_POST['input'];

// 2. Pecah data dengan "SPASI" menjadi data ARRAY
$split_data=explode(" ", $input);

// 3. Cek data ARRAY apakah mengandung angka
foreach ($split_data as $value) {
    if (!ctype_alpha($value)) { //tidak murni char(ada bilangan)
        $umur=$value;
    }
}

// 4. Pecah data Nama dan Kota yang dipisahkan dengan $umur
$split_data2=explode($umur, $input);

$nama=$split_data2[0];
$kota=$split_data2[1];  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data="John Doe 25YR London";

$arr = preg_split('/(?=\d)/', $data, 2);

if(count($arr) == 2) {
    $name = trim($arr[0]);
    $city = trim(strstr($arr[1], ' '));
    $age = trim(str_replace($city, '', $arr[1]));
}
```

Comment: -1 if it has three or four as name and surname? a lot of people got two names or two surnames or more

Comment: until the op tell more you have to asset that the first char as number will be age ;) you can work around your code i think to improve it

Comment: I know how to do it... But it will never be a foolproof solution... You could determine the first occurence of a number with preg_match, and everything before is the name, everything after until the first space is the age, and the rest is the city... But once again... not bulletproof

Comment: i'm not talking about foolproof, but handling more of the case will gain you a nice script for future use.. (even if it's better to save data splitted on the db eh) <_<

Comment: There you go my friend! @rezafahlevi08 Check the update on my answer.

Comment: +1, i think it's a good script and i will store it for future use (if i need it)